# Send github actions->CI result to Slack

Tags: github, github-actions, slack, slack-commands

I want to receive result of CI test in github actions to Slack.

Something like this:

[image]

Anybody knows how to do this or which tool should be used?

#### .github/workflows/verify.yml:

```
name: Verify CI
on: [push]

jobs:
  tests:
    name: Tests
    ...
```

Comment: You'll likely want to trigger on `status`, https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#status

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [slack-send](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/slack-send) GitHub Action to send data into Slack from your GitHub Workflow.

This Action can:

- Send data to Slack's Workflow Builder (requires a paid Slack instance).
- Send data via a Slack app to post to a specific channel (use an existing custom app or create a new one).
- Send data via a Slack Incoming Webhook URL (use an existing custom app or create a new one).

There are a [bunch of similar actions](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=slack+), for example, [slack - GitHub Actions Slack integration](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/slack-github-actions-slack-integration) - also simple and flexible Slack integration with GitHub Actions.